# FusionCharts Printing Problem

Tags: fusioncharts

I've been using FusionCharts v3.1 for a few years now.  For a long time we have had problems printing charts in Firefox but recently we've had problems printing charts in IE.  In IE, the charts print really, really small.

v3.2 was recently released and they have introduced the PrintManager that finally fixes the Firefox printing bug but the IE problem still exists.  I have heard that this is actually a Flash 10.1 problem but don't know for sure.

Any thoughts or workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that the problem truly is a flash issue.  I had Flash v10.1.53.64.  I just upgraded to Flash v10.1.85.3.  The chart printing problem with IE has gone away.

Hope this helps someone else :)